# Splitting list comprehension expression into multiple lines to understand what is going on better?

Tags: python, function, list-comprehension

I am trying to understand some code better, and there is one line that is doing a bunch of things that I'm not fully understanding. I was wondering if there's a way to split it up into multiple lines so I can get a better idea of what is happening in each step.

This code is part of a function and a long bit of code (many lines) so it's a bit hard to paste the whole code in here when this is just one line. However, I can do that if necessary or attach the code somehow. The line in particular I am talking about is a function where when given a partial assignment, it returns the full assignment. It's as follows:

```
return min([(sum([int(self.get_weight(assign, var, action)>0) for action in self.domains[var]]), var) for var in self.my_function if var not in assign])[1]
```

These are calling on a bunch of previously coded weights, etc. I'm just asking how you can split up this expression into multiple lines. Some thoughts I had were:

```
for var in self.my_function:
    if var not in assign:
        for action in self.domains...
```

Any thoughts on how to do this? I saw that an error was thrown up when I tried something like this, "unhashable type: list", so I know it's not quite the same expression. Thanks!

Comment: This type of question (improving working code) is better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @chepner "I am trying to understand some code better" indicates that the code wasn't written by OP, and thus is off-topic on Code Review. See also https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: someone gave you a straight garbage line of code.. never try to write your whole function in a single line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First split the original code across multiple lines:

```
min([
    (
        sum([
            int(self.get_weight(assign, var, action)>0) for action in self.domains[var]
        ]), var
    ) for var in self.my_function if var not in assign
])[1]
```

Which can be rewritten as:

```
list_to_take_min_of = []

for var in self.my_function:
    if var not in assign:
        weights = []
        for action in self.domains[var]:
            weights.append(int(self.get_weight(assign, var, action)>0))
        list_to_take_min_of.append((sum(weights), var))

min(list_to_take_min_of)[1]
```

Comment: (I hope I didn't make any typos or miss anything, please correct me if something is wrong)

Comment: Hi thank you, this helps a lot! This makes sense - so you can append two arguments to a list like this?

Comment: Whoops, @J.P. good catch, fixing! You can only append one element in `append`, but we get away by append a tuple (1 element) of 2 elements.

Comment: `l = [];l.append((1, 2))` will result in `[(1, 2)]`. And then you take a `min` of that: `min([(1, 2)]) => (1, 2)` and then you take the 2nd element from that result `(1, 2)[1] => 2`

Comment: Ah got it! So double parenthesis means tuple right? Thanks, will accept this :)

Comment: Well, actually commas are what define a tuple: `x = 1, 2` if you print `x`, you'll get `(1, 2)`, but if you don't include parentheses in the function call, it will think that you're trying to pass multiple arguments. The outer parenthesis belong to the `.append()` call.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just break up the original code into multiple lines to facilitate reading:

```
return min([(sum([int(self.get_weight(assign, var, action)>0) \
    for action in self.domains[var]]), var) \
        for var in self.my_function \
            if var not in assign])[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

When breaking up one liners, I find it helpful to take it one step at a time and follow the following template for each nested list comprehension:

```
out = [expression(value) for value in iterable if condition]

#becomes

out = []
for value in iterable:
    if condition
        out.append(
            expression(value)
        )
```

In your case you have a nested list comprehension, so `expression(...)` will be another copy of this boilerplate...